# Android In app billing refund policy - Does user has access to products after refund ?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have implemented Android In App billing. The last piece is handling refunds.

I understand the refunds are initiated by developer and the app will get a call back from IN_APP_NOTIFY. Do I still give the user the access to the product till end of subscription or not ?

I understand there is a policy when user cancels the subscription, we still need to give the user access till the end of subscription. But I am not sure about refunds. Is it upto the the developer to decide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once refunded, you can remove access to the product. You can track `purchaseState` in `INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA` json and if set to 2 (`refunded`), you can remove access to product in the app.